# get all UICollectionViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'd like to access all `UICollectionViewCell` in `UICollectionView`.
But in following code, Log outputs only `null`.
`CollectionCell` is subclass of UICollectionViewCell, and `titleLabel` is its property.
Do you have any idea to access all CollectionCell?

```
for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [collectionView numberOfSections]; j++) {
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:j]; i++) {
        CollectionCell* cell =　[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:j]];
        NSLog(@"%@", cell.titleLabel.text);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to cast `CollectionCell *cell = (CollectionCell *)[collectionView cellForRowItemAtIndex:Path:ZzZ];`?

Comment: why do you need all the cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**cellForItemAtIndexPath** only returns a **UICollectionViewCell** for visible cells.

One way to do this is call your datasource method

```
collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:
```

But remember: cells are reused, so you don't get unique cells